# Destroy the dialog box inside a partial view that sits inside the dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I call a partial view and load it in a dialog box. The link that calls the partial view looks like this:

```
 <div id="instructorSidebarDiv">
   @Html.ActionLink("My Schedule", "GetSchedule","Schedule", new { tester = 3 }, new { @class = "modal" })

 </div >
```

The script that loads the dialog box that contains the partial view looks like this:

```
      $(function () {
        $('#my-dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 700,
            height: 600,
            title: "Schedule",
            resizable: false,
            modal: false,
            buttons: {
                "Close Me": function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $('.modal').click(function () {
            $('#my-doialog').load(this.href, function () {
                $(this).dialog('open');
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

The ‘my-dialog’ is a `div` tag at the bottom of the page that loads the dialog box.  Everything works fine except I cannot close the dialog box with the button.  I've tried adding razor buttons and calling the click function to close them but nothing happens.

*My thinking is that the click function goes out of scope when after the dialog box loads.*

I can close the box by clicking on the x on the menu bar of the box but not with the usual close button at the bottom.  **How can I destroy the dialog box from inside a partial view that sits inside the dialog box?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing, this:

```
$(this).dialog("close");
```

To:

```
$('#my-dialog').dialog("close");
```